# Playing a video file on button click

Tags: android

Whenever I'll put this codes line into the button onClick event then it will gave me error ho to resolve it. The Error on a line of "mc = new MediaController(this); " and error is : 
("The constructor MediaController(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined")

```
public class TrialVideoActivity extends Activity  {

 public MediaController mc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

final Button play =(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
  play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View V){

  VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.lic);
  mc = new MediaController(this);
  vd.setMediaController(mc);
  vd.requestFocus();
  vd.setVideoURI(uri);
  vd.start();





      }
  });}
```

Whenever I played the video file directly then it will working perfectly but whenever I put it into the button click it will show the above error.
plz help me.

And one more thing how to increasing quality of video nad the buffering b'coz when the video is runing sound of the video is ok but the video going behind the sound...

Comment: chnage 'this' to TrialVideoActivity.this so it would loo like this.. mc = new MediaController(TrialVideoActivity.this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mc = new MediaController(this);
```

on this line you are passing **Context of Button click**, I think you should pass here **your Activity Context**.
For this you should declare a **Context**

**Private Context context;** inside Class and then inside **onCreat(**) you shiuld initialize it by

```
context = this;
```

and use

```
  mc = new MediaController(context);      // this is using context of Activity Class.
```

this is better way to resolve Context problem.

Comment: Thanks it will work tooo by adding it into a separate function and calling that method on button click

Comment: your problem was of Context, whatever way you choose to resolve that is your choise